# AngularJS scope binding difference between {foo : "="} and {foo : "=myFoo"}

Tags: angularjs, binding, scope

I've been working on some web apps in angular and have seen two different ways to bind variables on the scope. Whenever I thought that I've figured out what the difference is I always end up wrong. I've looked all over and can't find a clear answer to this.

What is the difference between

```
scope:
{
   foo : "="
}
```

and

```
scope:{
   foo : "=foo"
}
```

I've been using the top version and it seems to work well, but I would like to know what the bottom version is (and what the variables on both sides are for) so that I don't miss out on any powerful features angular has to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one allows you to map your scope to a different name in your markup.

Check out the example in the *Isolating the Scope of a Directive* section here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

This note gives some useful info:

> The scope option is an object that contains a property for each
>   isolate scope binding. In this case it has just one property:
>
> - Its name (customerInfo) corresponds to the directive's isolate scope property customerInfo.
> - Its value (=info) tells $compile to bind to the info attribute.

And this is pretty useful, too.

> These =attr attributes in the scope option of directives are
>   normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in bind-to-this="thing", you'd specify a binding of =bindToThis.